# Kuhn Poker - Blocker Effect - Probability Theory (Bayes Rule)

Tags: probability, bayesian

I am currently studying the blocker effect in the game Kuhn Poker [Kuhn Poker Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuhn_poker). Below you can see the game tree. At the first node, both players have 1/3 of one of the three possible cards (K, Q, J). These distributions can now change depending on the strategy of player 1 at the first node. Assuming player 1 always bets with the K, he obviously cannot hold this hand at the second node. At the same time, however, the probability distribution of player 2 also changes. For him, the probability of holding a K increases, since player 1 can only hold Q or J.

So much for the setting. I would now like to formulate the whole thing mathematically, see the second picture below. I could calculate the conditional probability for player 1 at the second node using Bayes' rule. For the probability distribution for player two I am stuck. How do I have to transform so that the initial probability p(h2 = K) = 1/3 appears in the formula? What is written below is more or less: p(h2 = K | h1 = K) = 0 (because both cannot hold the K), p(h2 = K | h1 = Q) = 1/2 and p(h2 = K | h1 = J) = 1/2... But somewhere the initial probability p(h2 = K,Q,J) = 1/3 must still occur, or not?

[image: First Picture]
[image]

Comment: Why are you assuming the first player always bets when holding a King? This is indeed one of several optimal strategies, but there are other equally good strategies (in terms of minimax expected gain) which involve sometimes slowplaying a King to induce a bluff from Player 2 holding a Jack. A better approach would be to realise that for each of the three cards a player has, Player 1 has three choices (Bet, or Check-Call, or Check-Fold) making $3^3=27$ pure strategies and Player 2 has four choices (Check/Fold, Check/Call, Bet/Fold, Bet/Call) making $4^3=64$ pure strategies...

Comment: .. If you want you can eliminate some of these as clearly sub-optimal (don't fold with a King, don't call with a Jack, and so don't bet with a Queen) reducing these.  But then you want to use copies of your original tree for each of the $6$ possible ways the cards are dealt to see the expected outcomes for the different pure strategies.

Comment: I know the optimal strategies of the game very well. However, I am not interested in them in my question, but I would like to formulate the blocker effect mathmatically properly. For this purpose, I have assumed in my example that player 1 always bets with the K.

Comment: If the blocker effect is "take account of what you are holding when considering what your opponent may hold" then I would have thought this means you need six copies of the trees rather than nine. In 52-card poker, it would not affect the number of trees but instead the probability of each. Do you think it means more than this?

Comment: You are right. You could create a subtree for every single combination of player 1 holding hand X and player 2 holding hand Y, where the set of all subtrees then corresponds to the entire game tree. My plot above represents this entire game tree by assuming a probability density at each node for the respective hands (K,Q,J) and each player. There is also another probability distribution at each node for the player who controls that node and must choose an action (fold, bet, call).

Comment: For example, at node 1 all probabilities are equal, i.e. p(K)=p(Q)=p(J)=1/3 for each player, since that is the probability with which the cards are dealt. Assuming player 1 always bets with a K and a Q at the first node and never with a J, i.e. p(a=bet | h=K) = p(a=bet | h=Q)=1 and p(a=bet | h=J) =0, then the probabilities for the respective hands at the second node change for both players. To be precise, the probability that player 2 holds a K or Q decreases and a J increases.

Comment: So if player 1 bets with King with probability $p_K$, with a Queen $p_Q$ and with a Jack $p_J$, you can say $\mathbb (\text{Player 1 has King} \mid  \text{Player 1 bets}) $ $=\frac{\frac13 p_K}{\frac13 p_K+\frac13 p_Q+\frac13 p_J} $ $=\frac{p_K}{ p_K+ p_Q+ p_J}$.  You can set some of $p_K,p_Q,p_J$ to $1$ or $0$ or something else if you want to explore particular scenarios.  That is the position at node 7.

Comment: At node 2 using the same conditional betting probabilities as before, it is $\mathbb (\text{Player 1 has King} \mid  \text{Player 1 checks}) $  $=\frac{1-p_K}{3- p_K- p_Q- p_J}$.

Comment: At node 9, if player 2 calls with King with probability $p_K$, with a Queen $q_Q$ and with a Jack $q_J$, you can say $\mathbb (\text{Player 1 has King and Player 2 has Queen} \mid  \text{Player 1 bets and Player 2 calls}) $ $=\frac{\frac16 p_Kq_Q}{\frac16  p_Kq_Q+\frac16  p_Kq_J+\frac16 p_Qq_K+\frac16 p_Qq_J+\frac16 p_Jq_K+\frac16 p_Jq_Q} $ $=\frac{p_Kq_Q}{p_Kq_Q+p_Kq_J+p_Qq_K+ p_Qq_J+ p_Jq_K+ p_Jq_Q}$.  You can do similar things for other nodes with the conditional probabilities of player 2 betting and of player 1 calling

Comment: Your first equation (Player 1 has K | Player 1 bets) is right and corresponds to my equations above under Node 2 - Player 1, if you replace a1=check with a1=bet. This is where I used Bayes rule. Everything is ok with this relationship. Where I struggle is the equation underneath (Node - Players 2). I want to know P(Player 2 holds K | Player 1 checked). I tried to integrate over all possible hands of Player 1 (sum over H), however, my problem is that my equation should include the initial probabilities p(K)=p(Q)=p(J)=1/3, but unfortunately it does not.

Comment: Using my previous $p_K,p_Q,p_R$ you get $\mathbb (\text{Player 2 has King} \mid  \text{Player 1 checks})$ $= \mathbb (\text{Player 2 has King} \mid  \text{Player 1 has Queen},\text{Player 1 checks})$ $\mathbb (\text{Player 1 has Queen} \mid  \text{Player 1 checks})$ $+ \mathbb (\text{Player 2 has King} \mid  \text{Player 1 has Jack},\text{Player 1 checks})$  $\mathbb (\text{Player 1 has Jack} \mid  \text{Player 1 checks})$ $=\frac12 \frac{(1-p_Q)}{3- p_K- p_Q- p_J} + \frac12 \frac{(1-p_J)}{3- p_K- p_Q- p_J}$ $=\frac{2-p_Q-p_J}{2(3- p_K- p_Q- p_J)}$

Comment: This is also right and corresponds to my equation under node 2 - player 2. My problem is that I want to further transform, e.g. the expression P(Player 2 has King | Player 1 has Jack, Player 1 checks) using standard rules of probability theory, e.g. sum and product rule. The final result should include the initial probability of holding a K at node 1, namly P(Player 2 has King)=1/3. Somewhere in between the indicator function has to occor, because both players cant be holding a K, but I'm unsure what rule to use, maybe independence, i dont know.

Comment: $\mathbb (\text{Player 2 has King} \mid  \text{Player 1 has Jack},\text{Player 1 checks}) =\frac12$ and it is $\frac12$ rather than $\frac13$ because if Player 1 has the Jack then Player 2 can only have the King or Queen. Player 1 checking adds no information when given the information that Player 1 holds the Jack

Comment: @Henry Your statement does hold for node 2, but not in general. Lets say, player 1 checked and player 2 checked aswell, so we arrive at node 3. What is the probability of player 1 holding the king? Formally: **(Player 1 has King | Player 1 checked, Player 2 checked) = f((Player 1 has King | Player 2 has Jack, Player 1 checked, Player 2 checked))**, where $f(\cdot)$ means that the probability does depend on its argument and others of course.

Comment: @Henry You will find that **(Player 1 has King | Player 2 has Jack, Player 1 checked, Player 2 checked) $\neq$ (Player 1 has Queen | Player 2 has Jack, Player 1 checked, Player 2 checked) $\neq \frac{1}{2}$** in general. Therefore, the action of one player does contain information.

Comment: You seem to be changing the question each time.  Suppose (given the chance) player 2 bets with probabilities $r_K,r_Q,r_J$. Then  $\mathbb P(\text{Player 1 has King} \mid  \text{Player 2 has Jack},\text{Player 1 checks},\text{Player 2 checks})$ $=\frac{\frac16(1-p_K)(1-r_J)}{\frac16(1-p_K)(1-r_J)+\frac16 (1-p_Q)(1-r_J)}$ $=\frac{1-p_K}{2-p_K-p_Q}$.  So this is unaffected by Player 2 checking but is affected by Player 2 having the Jack. 
Compare with my earlier $\mathbb (\text{Player 1 has King} \mid  \text{Player 1 checks})$ $=\frac{1-p_K}{3-p_K-p_Q-p_J}$

Comment: Sorry for mixing, but I got your point now. What we are dealing with is conditional independence $P(A | B,C) = P(A | B)$. Regarding node 2 and player 2 this means **(Player 2 has King | Player 1 has Jack, Player 1 checks) = (Player 2 has King | Player 1 has Jack)**. A bit more general and in my notation $P(h_2 \in H=\{K,Q,J\} | h_1 \in H, a_1=check) = P(h_2 | h_1) =
\begin{cases}
0, \text{if } h_2=h_1 \\
\frac{p(h_2)}{\sum_{h_2 \in H \setminus \{h_1\}}{p(h_2)}}, \text{else.}
\end{cases}$. Do you agree? Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Henry here's the solution to my problem:

[image]